# handle the docker image pull failed due to space issue in deployment

Tags: python, docker

I'm using a fab module (python) for the deployment. Sometimes I'm getting a message "failed to register layer: devmapper: Thin Pool has 1930 free data blocks which is less than minimum required 1944 free data blocks. Create more free space in thin pool or use dm.min_free_space option to change behavior" while pulling docker images at the time of deployment. If it's an error then i can handle it using try-except block. But here how to handle it.

If I got this kind of message, then the deployment job should get terminated.

Comment: I'd say the error is self explanatory. Docker does not have enough space - you need to give it more. Have a read of the relevant documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/)

Comment: That's fine, but my concern is if I got that message at the time of deployment then the deployment should get terminated using python.